# Search Excel with PowerShell and return cell address

Tags: excel, powershell

I have a PowerShell script which searches an Excel file for a server and then outputs details of the server. My script works but it is inefficient (see below).

What I would like to do is use the Excel Range.Find method for speed, but I can't get the right syntax for this to work in PowerShell.

In addition, is it possible to use PowerShell to open the Excel document, find the value being searched for and set the focus? It's the setting focus part that I struggled with.

Thanks in advance

```
Function SearchExcel{
#Specify the path of the excel file
$FilePath = "c:\temp\Servers.xlsx"

$ServerName="DC1"
#Specify the Sheet name
$SheetName = "VMs","Physical Servers"


$Row = 1
$Column = 1
$Found = $False

# Create an Object Excel.Application using Com interface
$objExcel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
# Disable the 'visible' property so the document won't open in excel
#$objExcel.Visible = $true
# Open the Excel file and save it in $WorkBook
$WorkBook = $objExcel.Workbooks.Open($FilePath)
# Load the WorkSheet 'BuildSpecs'

$WorkSheet = $WorkBook.sheets.item($SheetName[0])
$range=$WorkSheet.Range("a1:a500")

#Search Hyper-V sheet
while (($WorkSheet.Cells.Item($Row, $Column).Value() -ne $Null) -and ($Found -eq $False)) {

                                                                                    #^-- looping though the excel list, updating the row. Stop if Cell is Empty or Value is Found
    If (($WorkSheet.Cells.Item($Row, $Column).Value()) -eq $ServerName) {
                                                                                    #^-- Cell value equals $Arg
      Write-Host $WorkSheet.Cells.Item($Row, $Column).Value() $WorkSheet.Cells.Item($Row, $Column+1).Value(), $WorkSheet.Cells.Item($Row, $Column+2).Value(), $WorkSheet.Cells.Item($Row, $Column+3).Value(),$WorkSheet.Cells.Item($Row, $Column+4).Value(),"Cluster:" $WorkSheet.Cells.Item($Row, $Column+6).Value(), "Backed up by:" $WorkSheet.Cells.Item($Row, $Column+7).Value(),$WorkSheet.Cells.Item($Row, $Column+8).Value(),$WorkSheet.Cells.Item($Row, $Column+10).Value(),"vCPUs:" $WorkSheet.Cells.Item($Row, $Column+13).Value(),"RAM (GB):" $WorkSheet.Cells.Item($Row, $Column+14).Value(),"C: (GB):" $WorkSheet.Cells.Item($Row, $Column+15).Value(),"Page (GB):" $WorkSheet.Cells.Item($Row, $Column+16).Value(), "Total Disk (GB):" $WorkSheet.Cells.Item($Row, $Column+26).value().ToString(),$WorkSheet.Cells.Item($Row, $Column+24).Value()
     # write-host "processing"
      $Found = $True
    }
    $Row += 1                                                                       #Continue to the next row
  }#while

  write-host "Not found, searching second sheet"

  #If not found, search physical servers
    If ($found -eq $False)
        {
        #Search Physical VMs sheet
        $WorkSheet = $WorkBook.sheets.item($SheetName[1])
        $range=$WorkSheet.Range("a1:a200")

        while (($WorkSheet.Cells.Item($Row, $Column).Value() -ne $Null) -and ($Found -eq $False)) {
                                                                                       #^-- looping though the excel list, updating the row. Stop if Cell is Empty or Value is Found
    If (($WorkSheet.Cells.Item($Row, $Column).Value()) -eq $ServerName) {
                                                                                    #^-- Cell value equals $Arg
      Write-Host $WorkSheet.Cells.Item($Row, $Column).Value() $WorkSheet.Cells.Item($Row, $Column+1).Value(), $WorkSheet.Cells.Item($Row, $Column+21).Value(), $WorkSheet.Cells.Item($Row, $Column+22).Value(),$WorkSheet.Cells.Item($Row, $Column+23).Value(),"Cluster:" $WorkSheet.Cells.Item($Row, $Column+29).Value()
     # write-host "processing"
      $Found = $True
    }
    $Row += 1                                                                       #Continue to the next row
  }


    }#if

#Close Excel
  $workbook.close()
  $objExcel.Quit()
 }#Function 

  SearchExcel
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding content of Excel file in Powershell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30200920/finding-content-of-excel-file-in-powershell)

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I significantly sped this up by changing the line:

(($WorkSheet.Cells.Item($Row, $Column).Value() -ne $Null) -and ($Found -eq $False))

to

($row -le 500) -and ($Found -eq $False))

Comment: I would recommend trying the Range.Find method used in the linked question instead of the very slow cell by cell search

Answer (score 0):

You don't need search text cell by cell by PowerShell script. You can make use of the `Range.Find` method of Excel VBA object.

Below is the code maybe helpful to you.

```
Function Search-Sheet 
{ 
    [CmdletBinding()] 
    Param 
    ( 
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]$Sheet, 
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][String]$SearchText 
    ) 
    $firstResult = $result = $Sheet.UsedRange.Find($SearchText) 
    $allResults = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList 

    If ($firstResult -eq $null) { 
        Return $allResults 
    } 

    $processedResult = Compose-SearchResult -Result $result 
    $allResults.Add($processedResult) | Out-Null 

    $isSearchEnd = $false 
    Do { 
        $result = $Sheet.UsedRange.FindNext($result) 
        $isSearchEnd = Test-SearchResultSame -Result1 $result -Result2 $firstResult 
        If (-not $isSearchEnd) { 
            $processedResult = Compose-SearchResult -Result $result 
            $allResults.Add($processedResult) | Out-Null 
        } 
    } While (-not $isSearchEnd) 

    Return $allResults 
}
```

You can also download the complete sample script here [How to search text in Excel by PowerShell script](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/How-to-search-text-in-e16373b8)