# How to search a string in an Excel using Powershell

Tags: excel, powershell

I have a folder containing multiple excel files. I want to search for a string like "2501" and find which of my files contains this string then output it's file name to a file (or display it). I wrote some scripts and googled but did not find the answer.

I wrote this :

```
$Location = "C:\1.xlsx"
$SearchStr = "Mike"
$Sel = Select-String  -pattern $SearchStr -path $Location  
If ($Sel -eq $null)
{
write-host "$Location does not contain $SearchStr" -ForegroundColor Cyan
}
 Else 
{
    write-host "Found  $SearchStr  `n$Se in $Location"
}

 Write-host "end" -ForegroundColor Yellow
```

This works only if I specify a txt file, it does not work with Excel.

Comment: another example that works with txt files>>Get-Content c:\scripts\test.txt | Select-String "Failed"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30200920/finding-content-of-excel-file-in-powershell

Answer (score 0):

This may help https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/How-to-search-text-in-e16373b8

Also you may need to loop the folder to search in every excel file

Comment: I used this :$str="26123"
GET-CHILDITEM  -recurse C:\txt\*.txt | SELECT-STRING -pattern "\b$str\b"  >>F:\Final.txt
Write-Host Done -ForegroundColor Cyan    ---------but i first converted xlsx files to txt-tab delimited files

Comment: You are welcome :)
I followed the link I sent to you and it worked without converting the excel file to txt