# How to search an entire excel workbook for a particular string using powershell

Tags: excel, string, powershell, full-text-search

I need to search for a particular string in a excel spreadsheet that has multiple sheets in it. I am looking for a way to search the entire contents of the excel file similar to the Find All option in Excel with the scope set to the workbook and not just the worksheet.

It would be really nice if there was something similar to the search string for a particular string in regular file, (ie)

```
gci xcelfile.xls | select-string -pattern $mySearchString
```

I have searched the internet and I don't see much existing information for searching the contents of an existing excel file using powershell. I am hoping I can get some pointers here to get me to my goal.

Any assistance is much appreciated.
Thanks
Don

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30200920/finding-content-of-excel-file-in-powershell Perhaps. Assuming there is no global could easily enumerate all sheets

Comment: I used the select-string command above and it did find the string in the file, but the file has multiple worksheets and I need to pull the data from an adjoining column too.

the result I got contains a numeric value but I can't readily relate it to anything.

Comment: Matt,
Sorry, I read what you said but I don't know exactly what you mean.
What would that do for me and how would I do it?
Thanks

Comment: my search for 'a.b.c.d' returns a finding of 
excelfile.xls:328: a.b.c.d

and a second search that had the a IP that didn't exlude any other potential candidates gave me multiple inaccurate results:
excelfile.xls:
It's basically performing a search with a wild card on the end a.b.c.1*
192.168.22.1 would return any possible variant  .1, .1[0-9]

How can I limit the result to search for the more specific IP  a.b.c.1 ?

Comment: Your question and comments are getting a little all over the map. You know what you want to do. Breaking it up into parts is a good start. However you are not going to get all of your answers in one question. You cannot use `select-string` to search an excel file. It is not a flat text file. You need to use a 3rd party library or an Excel com object like the linked question shows.

Answer (score 2):

Opens Excel

Loads File

Loops through each worksheet

Searches a range

Loops through find next Outputs Index $Column$Row

Exits Excel

```
$File = "C:\TEST.xlsx"
$SearchString = "TEST"
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$Workbook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($File)
for($i = 1; $i -lt $($Workbook.Sheets.Count() + 1); $i++){
    $Range = $Workbook.Sheets.Item($i).Range("A:Z")
    $Target = $Range.Find($SearchString)
    $First = $Target
    Do
    {
        Write-Host "$i $($Target.AddressLocal())"
        $Target = $Range.FindNext($Target)
    }
    While ($Target -ne $NULL -and $Target.AddressLocal() -ne $First.AddressLocal())
}
$Excel.Quit()
```

Comment: I have learned better since I wrote up the answer linked in the comments. Now days I would recommend `ForEach($Sheet in $($Workbook.Sheets)){` for the loop, then you can do `$Target = $Sheet.UsedRange.Find($SearchString)`. Better to use the `UsedRange` than `Range("A:Z")` so that you are not searching more than you need to, and you are sure to capture all possible data.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician I loathe most of the code I wrote the day before